# How to pass HTML ID for input elements that have values

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have the following form for people to update image in the database
(by update image, basically just upload that new image, and update the image path)

```
<input type="file" name="color" id="1" />
<input type="file" name="color" id="2" />
<input type="file" name="color" id="3" />
...

<a onclick="submitFunc();" ></a>
```

How do I get the id value for my `submitFunc()` in php, so that I know which image people want to update?

if `($id==2)` is not empty, I know people want to update image #2, etc. but how do I pass that ID value?

Also it is possible that people update more than one file at a time.

Comment: You're going to need separate form elements for this.  I usually use arrayed names: `file[]`

Comment: How are you sending the information? Is it via a form or is it AJAX? What code do you already have?

Answer (score 5):

Add an array for the name instead, using the id as key:

```
<input type="file" name="color[1]"  />
<input type="file" name="color[2]"  />
<input type="file" name="color[3]"  />
```

Then in your recieving PHP check

```
if(is_array($_FILES['color'])):
  foreach ($_FILES['color'] as $id=>$file):
    if ($file['size']):
      // upload if changed. $id is your image id
```

Comment: Note: if the particular numbering or ordering is not important then the names can all simply be `name="color[]"`.

Comment: @Sammitch Sure. But as the script should replace some specific images the indexes are probably important in this case.